# Graphical Visualizer in terminal V[2]: using it visualizing: falling sand sim, sorting algorithms and the game of life

Tags: c++

this is the second version of this project, you can check previous post here: [Terminal Graphical Visualizer, using a queue of different matrices](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289059/terminal-graphical-visualizer-using-a-queue-of-different-matrices)
I implemented bare-bones version of ncurses library (without using it obviously), and using it I implemented 3 visualizations:

1. falling sand simulation - drop a line of sand particles of random length, if it encounters a particle below or the floor it stops, i used links of the send being dropped and removing the sand particle from the link if it encounters a position where it can't keep falling, it got 2 version of simulation, one it falls only in y axis and the second it can fall diagonally if encounters a particle below but diagonally down to the left or right is not occupied it falls there.
2. sorting algorithm visualization - sorts columns based on height and visualizing each step of the sort, I used the matrix of the falling sand and sorted it.
3. game of life - well it is the game of life I won't be posting the rules of it but you can search it up the rules are very simple, I added a function that configures the matrix to the glider gun.
   **Code:**
   ***graphical_visualizer.hpp***

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

const std::unordered_map<std::string, char const *> colors = {{"red", "\033[31m"}, {"green", "\033[32m"}, {"blue", "\033[34m"}, {"yellow", "\033[33m"}, {"reset", "\033[0m"}};

void gotoxy(size_t x, size_t y);

struct Pixel { // represents every single character on terminal
    char character;
    char const *color_code;

    bool operator==(Pixel const &compare);
    bool operator!=(Pixel const &compare);
};

using frame_matrix = std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>>;

class Frame { // consists of a pixel matrix, methods to manipulate and print the frame and consts for more flexebility
private:
    void initialize_frame();

    bool is_valid_input(std::string const &height_start, std::string const &height_length, std::string const &range_start, std::string const &range_length, std::string const &printable_char, std::string const &color);

public:
    frame_matrix current_frame;
    const static size_t AMOUNT_OF_INPUT_OPTIONS = 6;
    const static size_t FRAME_WIDTH = 40;
    const static size_t FRAME_HEIGHT = 20;
    const static char INPUT_DELIMITER = ',';
    const static char BACKGROUND = ' ';

    Frame();
    Frame(std::string const &input);

    frame_matrix get_current_frame() const;
    void alter_frame(std::string const &input);
    void set_current_frame(frame_matrix const &new_current_frame);
    void print_frame();
    void print_frame(Frame const &prev_frame);
    bool parse_input(std::string const &input);
};

class GraphicalVisualizer { // consists of a queue of frames and methods that manipulate the queue and prints the frames in order
private:
    std::queue<Frame> frame_queue;

public:
    GraphicalVisualizer();

    std::queue<Frame> get_frame_queue() const;
    void add_frame(Frame frame);
    void print_sequence(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis);
    void print_sequence_no_clear(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis);
};
```

***graphical_visualizer.cpp***

```
#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

void gotoxy(size_t x, size_t y) {
    std::cout << "\033[" << y << ";" << x << "H";
}

bool Pixel::operator==(Pixel const &compare) {
    return character == compare.character && std::strcmp(color_code, compare.color_code);
}

bool Pixel::operator!=(Pixel const &compare) {
    return character != compare.character || !std::strcmp(color_code, compare.color_code);
}

Frame::Frame() { initialize_frame(); }   // without parameters initializes the frame to an empty frame of FRAME::HEIGHT * FRAME::WIDTH filled with white FRAME::BACKGROUND characters
Frame::Frame(const std::string &input) { // with input from user initilizes the frame and sets it to according to the input
    initialize_frame();
    alter_frame(input);
}

frame_matrix Frame::get_current_frame() const { return current_frame; }

void Frame::alter_frame(std::string const &input) { // if parse_input found invalid input prints the message otherwise parse_input just does the job of actually altering the frame
    if (!parse_input(input))
        std::cout << "Invalid input \n";
}

void Frame::set_current_frame(frame_matrix const &new_current_frame) {
    current_frame = new_current_frame;
}

void Frame::print_frame() { // prints frame char by char first sets the color of the char then prints the char itself and then resets the color back to white
    for (auto const &line : current_frame) {
        for (auto const &current_pixel : line) {
            std::cout << current_pixel.color_code << current_pixel.character;
            std::cout << colors.at("reset");
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Frame::print_frame(Frame const &prev_frame) { // prints the frame using goto, used to print the frame without calling system("clear") every frame
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FRAME_WIDTH; ++j) {
            if (current_frame[i][j] != prev_frame.current_frame[i][j]) {
                gotoxy(j, i);
                std::cout << current_frame[i][j].color_code << current_frame[i][j].character;
                std::cout << colors.at("reset");
            }
        }
    }
}

bool Frame::parse_input(std::string const &input) { // parses the input that consists of "heigh_start,height_length,range_start,range_length,shape,color"
    std::stringstream input_stream(input);

    std::string input_sections[AMOUNT_OF_INPUT_OPTIONS];

    size_t input_sections_index = 0;
    while (std::getline(input_stream, input_sections[input_sections_index], INPUT_DELIMITER)) // inserts the input into sections of an array
        ++input_sections_index;

    if (!is_valid_input(input_sections[0], input_sections[1], input_sections[2], input_sections[3], input_sections[4], input_sections[5]))
        return false;

    int height_start = std::stoi(input_sections[0]); // convers input into usable types

    int height_length = std::stoi(input_sections[1]);

    int range_start = std::stoi(input_sections[2]);

    int range_length = std::stoi(input_sections[3]);

    char const *color = colors.at(input_sections[5]);

    char printable_char = input_sections[4][0]; // should always be a string of length 1

    for (size_t i = height_start; i <= height_start + height_length - 1; ++i) { // alters the frame based on the input
        for (size_t j = range_start; j <= range_start + range_length - 1; ++j) {
            current_frame[i][j].character = printable_char;
            current_frame[i][j].color_code = color;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void Frame::initialize_frame() { // initializes the frame with Frame::BACKGROUND and white color
    for (size_t i = 0; i < FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line;
        line.reserve(FRAME_WIDTH);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < FRAME_WIDTH; ++j)
            line.push_back({BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")});

        current_frame.push_back(line);
    }
}

bool is_a_number(std::string const &number) {
    for (char const &ch : number) {
        if (!std::isdigit(ch))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool Frame::is_valid_input(std::string const &height_start, std::string const &height_length, std::string const &range_start, std::string const &range_length, std::string const &printable_char, std::string const &color) {

    auto pos = colors.find(color);

    if (pos == colors.end())
        return false;

    if (!is_a_number(height_start) || !is_a_number(height_start) || !is_a_number(height_start) || !is_a_number(height_start)) { // checks if all passed numbers are actuall numbers
        return false;
    }
    if (printable_char.size() != 1)
        return false;

    int height_start_int = std::stoi(height_start);
    int height_length_int = std::stoi(height_length);
    int range_start_int = std::stoi(range_start);
    int range_length_int = std::stoi(range_length);

    // checks if the numbers passed are in range
    if (height_start_int < 0 ||
        height_length_int + height_length_int - 1 >= FRAME_HEIGHT ||
        range_start_int < 0 ||
        range_start_int + range_length_int - 1 >= FRAME_WIDTH)
        return false;
    return true;
}

GraphicalVisualizer::GraphicalVisualizer() { frame_queue = {}; } // initializes an empty queue

std::queue<Frame> GraphicalVisualizer::get_frame_queue() const {
    return frame_queue;
}

void GraphicalVisualizer::add_frame(Frame frame) { frame_queue.push(frame); } 

void GraphicalVisualizer::print_sequence(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis) { // accepts a parameter of time between each frame
    std::queue<Frame> local_temp_queue = frame_queue;

    while (local_temp_queue.size() > 1) { // prints the frame then pops it from the queue, sleeps for provided time and clears the terminal for the next frame

        local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
        local_temp_queue.pop();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(millis);
        system("clear");
    }

    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame(); // prints last frame without clearing it from the terminal
    local_temp_queue.pop();
}

// prints the frames same as print_sequence but without using system("clear") insted providing the previous frame so it can just update the pixels that are different
void GraphicalVisualizer::print_sequence_no_clear(const std::chrono::milliseconds millis) {
    std::queue<Frame> local_temp_queue = frame_queue;
    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
    while (local_temp_queue.size() > 1) {
        Frame last_frame = local_temp_queue.front();
        local_temp_queue.pop();
        local_temp_queue.front().print_frame(last_frame);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(millis);
        // system("clear");
    }

    local_temp_queue.front().print_frame();
    local_temp_queue.pop();
    system("clear");
}
```

***falling_sand.hpp***

```
#pragma once

#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

const char SAND_SHAPE = '@';
const std::string SAND_DEFAULT_COLOR = "red";
const int SAND_BLOCK_AMOUNT = 15;
const int MIN_SAND_LENGTH = 5;
const int MAX_SAND_LENGTH = 15;
const std::chrono::milliseconds millis_per_frame_falling_sand = 20ms;

struct SandBlock { // represent a line of falling sand, each line consists of vector of pairs that represent the position of each sand particle within the block
    int length;
    int starting_position;
    char shape;
    std::string color;
    std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> links;

    SandBlock();
    SandBlock(std::string color);
};

class FallingSand { // consists of a frame that changes, the visualizer that prints the frames and a queue of sand blocks that after reaching a stop the next in queue falls
private:
    Frame field;
    GraphicalVisualizer visualizer;
    std::queue<SandBlock> sand_blocks;

public:
    FallingSand();
    void generate_sand_blocks();
    void simulate_fall();
    void simualte_diag_fall();

    Frame get_field() const;
};
```

***falling_sand.cpp***

```
#include "falling_sand.hpp"

#include <random>

int generate_random_length() {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(MIN_SAND_LENGTH, MAX_SAND_LENGTH); // distribution in range [MIN_SAND_LENGTH, MAX_SAND_LENGTH]

    return dist(rng);
}

int generate_random_start_pos(int sand_length) {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, Frame::FRAME_WIDTH - sand_length);

    return dist(rng);
}

SandBlock::SandBlock() { // generate random starting possition and length of the block and the pushes the particles into the vector of links
    length = generate_random_length();
    starting_position = generate_random_start_pos(length);
    shape = SAND_SHAPE;
    color = SAND_DEFAULT_COLOR;
    for (size_t i = starting_position; i <= starting_position + length - 1; ++i) {
        links.push_back({0, i});
    }
}

SandBlock::SandBlock(std::string color) : color(color) { // same as without params but sets the color to the provided one instead of default const
    length = generate_random_length();
    starting_position = generate_random_start_pos(length);
    shape = SAND_SHAPE;
    for (size_t i = starting_position; i <= starting_position + length - 1; ++i) {
        links.push_back({0, i});
    }
}

FallingSand::FallingSand() {
    generate_sand_blocks();
    // simulate_fall();
    simualte_diag_fall();
    system("clear");
    visualizer.print_sequence(millis_per_frame_falling_sand);
}

void FallingSand::generate_sand_blocks() {
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= SAND_BLOCK_AMOUNT; ++i) {

        sand_blocks.push(SandBlock());
    }
}

void FallingSand::simulate_fall() { // the simulation itself this is version without daig falls of sand particles only in the y axis

    while (!sand_blocks.empty()) {
        SandBlock current_block = sand_blocks.front();

        bool did_move = true;
        while (did_move) {
            did_move = false;
            visualizer.add_frame(field); // adds the current state of frame to the visualizer queue

            frame_matrix new_frame = field.get_current_frame();

            for (size_t i = 0; i < current_block.links.size(); ++i) {
                std::pair<size_t, size_t> link = current_block.links[i]; // tracks the current sand particle

                // checks for bounds
                if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character != current_block.shape) {
                    did_move = true;
                    // resets the color and shape of current place, then updates the color and shape of the one below
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                    current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                }
            }

            field.set_current_frame(new_frame);
        }
        sand_blocks.pop();
    }
}

int generate_random_direction() { // generates random direction for diag fall either fall left or right
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, 1);

    return dist(rng);
}

void FallingSand::simualte_diag_fall() {
    while (!sand_blocks.empty()) {
        SandBlock current_block = sand_blocks.front();

        bool did_move = true;
        while (did_move) {
            did_move = false;
            visualizer.add_frame(field);
            frame_matrix new_frame = field.get_current_frame();

            for (size_t i = 0; i < current_block.links.size(); ++i) {
                std::pair<size_t, size_t> link = current_block.links[i];
                // same as without diag fall but it does not stop when encounters anothe particle below
                if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character != current_block.shape) {
                    did_move = true;
                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                    current_block.links[i].first += 1;

                    new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                } else if (link.first != Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second].character == current_block.shape) {

                    int direction = generate_random_direction();

                    // checks if generated 1 in direction and also for bounds and posibility to fall diagonally to the left else checks right
                    if (link.second != Frame::FRAME_WIDTH - 1 && direction == 1 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second + 1].character != current_block.shape) {
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                        current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                        current_block.links[i].second += 1;
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                    } else if (link.second != 0 && field.get_current_frame()[link.first + 1][link.second - 1].character != current_block.shape) {
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
                        current_block.links[i].first += 1;
                        current_block.links[i].second -= 1;
                        new_frame[current_block.links[i].first][current_block.links[i].second] = {current_block.shape, colors.at(current_block.color)};
                    }
                }
            }

            field.set_current_frame(new_frame);
        }
        sand_blocks.pop();
    }
}

Frame FallingSand::get_field() const {
    return field;
}
```

***algorithm_visualizer.hpp***

```
#pragma once

#include "falling_sand.hpp"
#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

using grid = std::vector<std::pair<int, char const *>>; // represents the frame in heights of columns and remembers the color of the column
const std::chrono::milliseconds millis_per_frame_algo_vis = 50ms;

class AlgorithmVisualizer { // consists of the visualizer to print the frames, a frame that is changing and different kind of sorting algos that works on grid
private:
    GraphicalVisualizer visualizer;
    Frame to_sort;

public:
    AlgorithmVisualizer(Frame to_sort, char symbol);

    std::vector<std::pair<int, char const *>> frame_matrix_to_num(frame_matrix convert_from, char symbol_to_count);
    frame_matrix num_to_frame_matrix(std::vector<std::pair<int, char const *>> convert_from, char symbol_to_insert);

    void bubble_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol);
    void merge_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol);
    void merge_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol, size_t start, size_t end, std::vector<std::pair<int, char const *>> &printable_frame);
    void quick_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol, size_t start, size_t end);
};
```

***algorithm_visualizer.cpp***

```
#include "algorithm_visualizer.hpp"
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

char const *generate_random_color() {
    std::random_device dev;
    std::mt19937 rng(dev());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, colors.size() - 1);
    auto it = colors.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dist(rng); ++i) {
        it++;
    }
    if (it->first == "reset")
        return colors.at("red");
    return it->second;
}

void change_frame_colors(Frame &frame_to_color, char symbol_to_color) {

    for (size_t j = 0; j < frame_to_color.current_frame[0].size(); ++j) {

        char const *color = generate_random_color();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < frame_to_color.current_frame.size(); ++i) {
            if (frame_to_color.current_frame[i][j].character == symbol_to_color)
                frame_to_color.current_frame[i][j].color_code = color;
        }
    }
}

AlgorithmVisualizer::AlgorithmVisualizer(Frame to_sort, char symbol) : to_sort(to_sort) { // place the algorithm to visualize in the body remove or comment the others

    change_frame_colors(to_sort, SAND_SHAPE);
    grid frame_to_vec = frame_matrix_to_num(to_sort.current_frame, symbol);
    // bubble_sort(frame_to_vec, symbol);
    //  merge_sort(frame_to_vec, symbol);
    quick_sort(frame_to_vec, symbol, 0, frame_to_vec.size());
    system("clear");
    visualizer.print_sequence(millis_per_frame_algo_vis);
}

grid AlgorithmVisualizer::frame_matrix_to_num(frame_matrix convert_from, char symbol_to_count) { // converts a frame matrix into a vector of numbers and colors so the soring algos can work on it
    grid convert_to;
    // calculate the height of each column
    for (size_t i = 0; i < convert_from[0].size(); ++i) {
        int symbol_counter = 0;
        char const *color = colors.at("reset");
        for (size_t j = 0; j < convert_from.size(); ++j) {
            if (convert_from[j][i].character == symbol_to_count) {
                symbol_counter++;
                color = convert_from[j][i].color_code;
            }
        }
        convert_to.push_back({symbol_counter, color});
    }
    return convert_to;
}

frame_matrix AlgorithmVisualizer::num_to_frame_matrix(grid convert_from, char symbol_to_insert) { // converts the grid back into a frame_matrix so it could be inserted into the visualizer queue
    frame_matrix convert_to;
    // initializes a frame
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < Frame::FRAME_WIDTH; ++j)
            line.push_back({Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")});

        convert_to.push_back(line);
    }

    int matrix_index = 0;
    // places the shape and color to insert into the frame goes column by column
    for (auto height : convert_from) {
        if (height.first >= Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT)
            return {};
        for (int j = 0; j < height.first; ++j) {
            convert_to[convert_to.size() - j - 1][matrix_index] = {symbol_to_insert, height.second};
        }
        matrix_index++;
    }
    return convert_to;
}

void AlgorithmVisualizer::bubble_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vect_to_sort.size() - 1; ++i) {
        bool is_swapped = false;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < vect_to_sort.size() - i - 1; ++j) {
            to_sort.set_current_frame(num_to_frame_matrix(vect_to_sort, symbol));
            visualizer.add_frame(to_sort);
            if (vect_to_sort[j].first >= vect_to_sort[j + 1].first) {
                std::swap(vect_to_sort[j], vect_to_sort[j + 1]);
                is_swapped = true;
            }
        }
        if (!is_swapped)
            break;
    }
}

void AlgorithmVisualizer::merge_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol) {
    if (vect_to_sort.size() <= 1)
        return;

    size_t mid = (vect_to_sort.size() / 2);
    grid left(vect_to_sort.cbegin(), vect_to_sort.cbegin() + mid);
    grid right(vect_to_sort.cbegin() + mid, vect_to_sort.cend());
    vect_to_sort.clear();
    merge_sort(left, symbol);
    merge_sort(right, symbol);

    size_t left_index = 0;
    size_t right_index = 0;
    while (vect_to_sort.size() < left.size() + right.size()) {
        if (left_index == left.size())
            vect_to_sort.insert(vect_to_sort.end(), right.begin() + right_index, right.end());
        else if (right_index == right.size())
            vect_to_sort.insert(vect_to_sort.end(), left.begin() + left_index, left.end());
        else {
            if (left[left_index].first > right[right_index].first) {
                vect_to_sort.push_back(left[left_index]);
                left_index++;
            } else {
                vect_to_sort.push_back(right[right_index]);
                right_index++;
            }
        }
    }

    to_sort.set_current_frame(num_to_frame_matrix(vect_to_sort, symbol));
    visualizer.add_frame(to_sort);
}

// same as the default merge_sort but with saving the new vector shape so the frame can show the whole vector changing
void AlgorithmVisualizer::merge_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol, size_t start, size_t end, grid &printable_frame) {
    if (vect_to_sort.size() <= 1)
        return;

    size_t mid = (vect_to_sort.size() / 2);
    grid left(vect_to_sort.cbegin(), vect_to_sort.cbegin() + mid);
    grid right(vect_to_sort.cbegin() + mid, vect_to_sort.cend());
    vect_to_sort.clear();
    merge_sort(left, symbol, start, mid, printable_frame);
    merge_sort(right, symbol, mid, end, printable_frame);

    size_t left_index = 0;
    size_t right_index = 0;
    while (vect_to_sort.size() < left.size() + right.size()) {
        if (left_index == left.size())
            vect_to_sort.insert(vect_to_sort.end(), right.begin() + right_index, right.end());
        else if (right_index == right.size())
            vect_to_sort.insert(vect_to_sort.end(), left.begin() + left_index, left.end());
        else {
            if (left[left_index].first > right[right_index].first) {
                vect_to_sort.push_back(left[left_index]);
                left_index++;
            } else {
                vect_to_sort.push_back(right[right_index]);
                right_index++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vect_to_sort.size(); ++i) {
        if (start < end) {
            printable_frame[start] = vect_to_sort[i];
            start++;
        }
    }

    to_sort.set_current_frame(num_to_frame_matrix(printable_frame, symbol));
    visualizer.add_frame(to_sort);
}

void AlgorithmVisualizer::quick_sort(grid &vect_to_sort, char symbol, size_t start, size_t end) {
    if (end - start <= 0)
        return;

    size_t pivot = end - 1;
    size_t first_bigger_than_pivot = start;
    bool is_bigger_found = vect_to_sort[first_bigger_than_pivot].first > vect_to_sort[pivot].first;
    for (size_t i = start; i < pivot; ++i) {
        if (!is_bigger_found && vect_to_sort[i].first > vect_to_sort[pivot].first) {
            is_bigger_found = true;
            first_bigger_than_pivot = i;
        }
        if (is_bigger_found && vect_to_sort[i].first <= vect_to_sort[pivot].first) {
            std::rotate(vect_to_sort.begin() + first_bigger_than_pivot, vect_to_sort.begin() + i, vect_to_sort.begin() + i + 1);
            to_sort.set_current_frame(num_to_frame_matrix(vect_to_sort, symbol));
            visualizer.add_frame(to_sort);
            first_bigger_than_pivot += 1;
        }
    }

    if (is_bigger_found) {
        std::swap(vect_to_sort[pivot], vect_to_sort[first_bigger_than_pivot]);
        pivot = first_bigger_than_pivot;
        to_sort.set_current_frame(num_to_frame_matrix(vect_to_sort, symbol));
        visualizer.add_frame(to_sort);
    }

    quick_sort(vect_to_sort, symbol, start, pivot);
    quick_sort(vect_to_sort, symbol, pivot + 1, end);
}
```

***game_of_life.hpp***

```
#pragma once

#include "graphical_visualizer.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

namespace game_of_life {
    char const CELL_SHAPE = '*';
    std::string const CELL_COLOR = "blue";
    const std::chrono::milliseconds millis_per_frame_game_of_life = 100ms;
}

bool is_cell_alive(frame_matrix const &grid, size_t x, size_t y);

void simulate_game_of_life(Frame &frame, size_t amount_of_cycles, void (*game_conf)(frame_matrix &));

void glider_gun_conf(frame_matrix &grid);
```

***game_of_life.cpp***

```
#include "game_of_life.hpp"

#include <set>

bool is_cell_alive(frame_matrix const &grid, size_t x, size_t y) {
    int amount_of_neighbors = 0;
    if (x > 0) {
        if (grid[y][x - 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
        if (y > 0 && grid[y - 1][x - 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
        if (y < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && grid[y + 1][x - 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
    }
    if (x < Frame::FRAME_WIDTH - 1) {
        if (grid[y][x + 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
        if (y > 0 && grid[y - 1][x + 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
        if (y < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && grid[y + 1][x + 1].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
            ++amount_of_neighbors;
    }

    if (y > 0 && grid[y - 1][x].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
        ++amount_of_neighbors;
    if (y < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT - 1 && grid[y + 1][x].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE)
        ++amount_of_neighbors;

    if (grid[y][x].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE && amount_of_neighbors < 2)
        return false;
    else if (grid[y][x].character == game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE && amount_of_neighbors > 3)
        return false;
    else if (grid[y][x].character == Frame::BACKGROUND && amount_of_neighbors != 3)
        return false;

    return true;
}

void simulate_game_of_life(Frame &frame, size_t amount_of_cycles, void (*game_conf)(frame_matrix &)) {
    GraphicalVisualizer visualizer;
    game_conf(frame.current_frame);
    visualizer.add_frame(frame);
    for (size_t cycle = 1; cycle <= amount_of_cycles; ++cycle) {
        std::set<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> alive_cells;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < Frame::FRAME_WIDTH; ++j) {
                if (is_cell_alive(frame.current_frame, j, i))
                    alive_cells.insert({j, i});
            }
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Frame::FRAME_WIDTH; ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT; ++j) {
                auto find_cell = alive_cells.find({i, j});
                if (find_cell != alive_cells.cend())
                    frame.current_frame[j][i] = {game_of_life::CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(game_of_life::CELL_COLOR)};
                else
                    frame.current_frame[j][i] = {Frame::BACKGROUND, colors.at("reset")};
            }
        }
        visualizer.add_frame(frame);
    }
    visualizer.print_sequence(game_of_life::millis_per_frame_game_of_life);
}

void glider_gun_conf(frame_matrix &grid) {
    size_t ref_point_y = Frame::FRAME_HEIGHT / 4;
    size_t ref_point_x = Frame::FRAME_WIDTH / 4;

    using namespace game_of_life;
    // left square
    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    // left square

    // middle part 10 to right
    ref_point_x += 10;

    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 2][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 1][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 3][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 2][ref_point_x + 2] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 4][ref_point_x + 2] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 2][ref_point_x + 3] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 4][ref_point_x + 3] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x + 4] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 1][ref_point_x + 5] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 3][ref_point_x + 5] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x + 6] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x + 6] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 2][ref_point_x + 6] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x + 7] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    // middle part

    // right part
    ref_point_x += 10;
    ref_point_y -= 2;

    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 2][ref_point_x] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 1][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 2][ref_point_x + 1] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 1][ref_point_x + 2] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 3][ref_point_x + 2] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 1][ref_point_x + 4] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y - 2][ref_point_x + 4] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 3][ref_point_x + 4] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    grid[ref_point_y + 4][ref_point_x + 4] = {CELL_SHAPE, colors.at(CELL_COLOR)};
    // right part
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "algorithm_visualizer.hpp"
#include "falling_sand.hpp"
#include "game_of_life.hpp"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int, char **) {

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    FallingSand simualtion;
    AlgorithmVisualizer algo_vis(simualtion.get_field(), SAND_SHAPE);

    Frame frame;
    simulate_game_of_life(frame, 100, &glider_gun_conf);

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << "Execution time: " << duration.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

couple of notes: in graphical_visualizer I tried adding another version of printing the sequence without using clear it semi-works and I still prefer the system("clear") because I got annoyed trying to solve stupid bugs with it.
second in algorithm_visualizer I have 2 versions of merge sort, one is prints sequence of sorted sub arrays, the second shows the whole array getting sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall seems really cute, but here are some possible points for improvements:

- generate_random_direction is a free function inside some cpp file of a class. I might be a better practice to make it a private function (maybe even private static function) of the class.
- simualte_diag_fall seems like a really big function. I think it'd be better to split it into multiple functions.
- millis_per_frame_game_of_life is out of naming convention.
- For free functions, consider using a namespace to make it more encapsulated.

Overall seems good! Good luck!